Determining chance level for forced-choice performance validity tests
Psychologists, especially neuropsychologists, use performance validity tests (PVTs) to detect individuals who might intentionally underperform on ability tests, e.g., memory tests, because diagnosed cognitive deficits might lead to desired results (from the test-taker's perspective), e.g., disability compensation payments.
Say you have a forced-choice PVT with 60 items. The median error score for people with no psychiatric disorder is 1, and for people with severe mental disorders, e.g., schizophrenia, the median score is 5. Based on cross-validated research, a cut score of 9 or higher is designated to identify dissimulation, i.e., probable feigning. Of course, psychologists should not conclude the person was malingering based on only one PVT score.
But what if an error score is so high that the odds of achieving the score by chance are very low? In other words, the person had to really work hard to repeatedly give the wrong answer.
Example: A subject applying for disability benefits produces an error score of 39.
What are the odds that simply by flipping a coin  you would produce an error score of 39 or higher on our hypothetical 60-item forced-choice PVT?

Please let me know if anything in my question is unclear or could be phrased better so that I can edit it and improve the quality of information we offer on StackExchange.

I found one post on this stack that I believe answers the question: How do I determine/compute a cutoff for chance level/not chance level?
But I wanted post this question-and-answer for the benefit of others searching the internet using psychology language—there is not much available online, and what's there is hard to find. Plus, I like to attract people to StackExchange.
Here's the answer: Plug the numbers into a Binomial Probability Calculator as follows.

Probability of success on a trial: 0.5
Number of trials: 60
Number of successes (x): 21

Click "calculate" and the answer is the cumulative probability of 21 or fewer correct answers (39 or more errors), which is 0.01367 or 1.4% (rounding up).
Thus, a psychologist could write something like this in a report:

"Hypothetically, if a person answered the test items based on a coin toss, the odds of producing 39 or more wrong answers is 1.4%."


Please let me know if anything in my answer is misleading or inaccurate and I will edit the answer.
